# How to show/hide invisible files and folders from Service menu?

Tags: macos, terminal, finder, automator

How to show/hide invisible files and folders from Service menu?

By default files and folders whose name start with . is invisible. In order to show them, you can use the following command in Terminal.

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -boolean true; killall Finder
```

To restore the default state, in which those files are hidden, use the following.

```
defaults delete com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles; killall Finder
```

How can I toggle the status of `AppleShowAllFiles` key without launching Terminal?

Answer (score 2):

Apologies if this is a little off-topic from your question, but, in macOS Sierra you can toggle showing hidden files right in the Finder with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

1. Launch **Automator**
2. Choose **Service** for new document.
3. From "Actions" menu, choose **Utilities** > **Run Shell Script**. Double click it in the menu, or drag and drop it into the right pane.
4. Make sure "Service receives" is set to **no input** in **Finder**
5. Add the following shell script into the **Run Shell Script**

   ```
   S1=`defaults read com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles`
   C1='defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -boolean'

   # spaces within brackets are important
   if [[ $S1 == '1' ]]; then
   $C1 false
   elif [[ $S1 == '0' ]]; then
   $C1 true
   else 
   # does not exist
   $C1 true
   fi
   killall Finder
   ```
6. **Save** it with an appropriate name such as "ToggleInvisible"
7. Make sure in **System Preference** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services** > **General**, the service you created is shown and ticked.
8. Now go to Finder and click Finder menu > Services > "ToggleInvisible" (or your choice of name) to see the effect.

Or if you prefer, choose **Application** instead of Service at the beginning in Automator.